# Como coletar texto quando não tem classe HTML de referência

Tags: python, web-scraping, svg, scraping

Estou tentando puxar os dados desse código da imagem. O que me interessa é a leta I onde está marcado de vermelho.

Já tentei dessa forma abaixo, mas não deu certo:

url = 'https://blaze.com/pt/games/football-studio'

html_page = requests.get(url)
html_source = html_page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')

dados_site = soup.find_all('text')

print(dados_site)

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QG0l.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

BeautifulSoup tem suporte de seleção em CSS - use um metodos select() ou select_one():

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
elements = soup.select("#left-container > div.left-content > div > div > ul")
```

Certifique-se de usar a versão 4.7.0 ou superior para ter suporte para a maioria dos seletores CSS4.

Answer (score -3):

Eu não sei em Python, mas se for em JS você pode usar a função querySelector

```
document.querySelector('g text');
```

a função querySelector como o nome já informa serve para selecionar um parametro. no caso acima eu selecionei o pai e o filho, então retornará o campo que você está querendo.

Também pode ser usado o querySelectorAll() que seleciona todos os elementos com esses parametros.

Comment: Vou fazer o teste e te falo se conseguir. Obrigado!!

Comment: Porque do menos -1 ?

Comment: cliquei errado.

Comment: É possível fazer essa coleta de dados usando o Python?